# Is it possible to set a fallback for a route destination in virtual service?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-service

Here is how my **virtual service** currently looks like -

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: example-route
spec:
  hosts:
 - example.com
  http:
 - match:
    - port: 443
    - uri:
        prefix: "/catalog" 
   route:
    - destination:
        host: catalog-server.ns.svc.cluster.local
 - match:
    - port: 443
   route:
    - destination:
        host: general-server.ns.svc.cluster.local
```

What I want is to set a fallback or default host for the destination host (catalog-server.ns.svc.cluster.local) in virtual service/istio?

I expect something like this

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: example-route
spec:
  hosts:
 - example.com
  http:
 - match:
    - port: 443
    - uri:
        prefix: "/catalog" 
   route:
    - destination:
        host: catalog-server.ns.svc.cluster.local
      fallback:
        host: general-server.ns.svc.cluster.local

 - match:
    - port: 443
   route:
    - destination:
        host: general-server.ns.svc.cluster.local
```

**use case:**
When there is heavy traffic in "/catalog", I turn up a catalog server, which is the same as general server but exclusive for the request type.
So when catalog server is up, the "/catalog" requests must be forwarded to catalog-servers, and when down, it must be forwarded to general servers. And I cannot update virtual service every time I launch or remove catalog-servers.

Answer (score 1):

Istio does provide some support for circuit breaking as described in https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking/

However, afaik there is no support for fallbacks. This probably means that the application would have to call the fallback if the main service is down.

Comment: Hmm perhaps it's a bit hacky but could work with circuit breaking: if OP defines a "both-general-and-catalog" service that selects pods of both, define subsets "general" and "catalog", then setup weighted load balancing to have most traffic sent to "catalog", and with finally a circuit breaker (outlier detection) to evict catalog for some time upon failures. It could work I guess...

Comment: @Joel Well yes it sound quite hacky, so I would still opt for the application to that that